# Create full HTML file using partial HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dhtml

I have a main html page (index.html) and need to construct that page page dynamically combining several html files `(custom_header_page.html/ custom_content_page.html/ custom_footer_page.html)`.

I am looking for a way to get it done **without** any **server side scripting** invloving.

**Eg:**

***custom_header_page.html***

[image]

***custom_body_page.html***

[image]

***custom_footer_page.html***

[image]

---

Just tired with following in the index.html file and yes it loads properly but I want to override the `<head> </head>` content of my index.html with what I have added in "custom_header.html" file.

***index.html***

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="custom_header"></div>

    <div id="custom_body"></div>

    <div id="custom_footer"></div>

    <script> 
        $(function(){
          $("#custom_header").load("custom_header_page.html"); 
          $("#custom_body").load("custom_body_page.html"); 
          $("#custom_footer").load("custom_footer_page.html"); 
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that anyway?

Comment: Server loads index file dynamically according to the partial html information we provide. This is to setup locally in a folder to simulate the process to check the design before send them. Yes we can test it locally editing in browser using web developer tools, but the idea is to do this later by someone who is not familiar with HTML and these. Change CSS stuff with different header and footer images etc.

Comment: The way you do it now would create invalid HTML. Your page would have extra `html` and `body` tags. It is also not recommended to do this for SEO.

Comment: Why not use php? `<?php echo $header; ?>` seems a lot better than using jquery when even if you didnt use php you could use vanilla js and save some load time. Im not sure I understand your overall logic here

Comment: @putvande you are correct unless he changes the selector to load. Ie `load ('url.com  #idOrClassOfElement');` and yes the search engine would not see these html files itll only see blank document you have to know what search engines actually see when crawling